# Android WindowManager.updateViewLayout behaving weird

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

This is part of my code in my view:

```
params.width = MyActivity.getWidth();
params.FOCUSED.height = MyActivity.getHeight();

wm.updateViewLayout(this, WindowLayoutParams.FOCUSED);
```

I'm trying to re-size the window with touch messages.

When I call updateViewLayout() it translates the coords to (0,0) and resizes it.
The problem is I can see it happening. So it flickers. how do i update my view without this happening?
(I have tried with the handler and it doesn't work)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: same problem with me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725813/view-behave-weirdly-when-updating-its-layoutparams-using-windowmanager